# Pairing dispatch_resume and dispatch_suspend for forced app kill

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

If you're creating and managing timers via GCD with `dispatch_source_create, dispatch_resume and dispatch_suspend`, I know that you have to always make sure that for every dispatch_suspend, there has to be a matching `dispatch_resume`.

So when an application enters background mode, you would call dispatch_suspend and upon receiving `applicationDidBecomeActive`, call `dispatch_resume` on the timer sources that were previously suspended.

What about the `dispatch_resume` when an application was force killed (via bringing up the list of apps running in background)? Do you have to worry about it all? I presume that when the app is restarted, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is invoked as if the app is starting cleanly.. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If your backgrounded app gets killed by the user via the multitasking tray, or killed by the system to free up memory, launching the app again will be just the same as launching it for the first time.